Getting `segmentation fault` while running a video using `cvlc`
I have a raspberry pi model 4B.
This the os version I have
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

I'm trying to run a video using cvlc.
When I run the video from my remote terminal, the video runs successfully on my Raspberry Pi.
To run the video on my Raspberry screen I first need to export the DISPLAY env variable, which I figured out from Here. DISPLAY env variable is needed otherwise it starts playing video as ascii within the terminal.
Here are the steps to run a video from the remote SSH terminal. It shows some errors, but runs the video.

When I try to run the same video from inside the rasbperry from raspberry built-in terminal, it shows segmentation fault.

I have an external display is attached with my raspberry with a HDMI cable.
Do anyone has any idea why this is happening, I actually wanted to create a program using python-vlc, but same issue when I use it from python. I digged into the issue and found it's cvlc that actually shows the issue down the line. Can anyone guide me the direction of how I can fix this error?

A segmentation fault is indicative of a software bug, unfortunately.

@goldilocks Is there any way to solve it? and which software has this bug either raspberry terminal or vlc? as I see it works from remote ssh terminal.

It's not the terminal since the terminal reports the problem, and these are things that cannot be caught and reported by the software itself (or at least, if they do it would be reported differently); they are memory access errors that are blocked by the OS and the process itself is then destroyed.  So it is clvc or some component it is closely bound to.  The fact that it happens in one context but not another is unlikely to be very meaningful except to people with an inside perspective on the software trying to solve the bug.

You clarify that you know you are using X11 and not Wayland, since the latter is the default on bookworm, but it seems above that it is the former (which is something you would have had to change manually).  If not something strange is going on, I am not sure how it would relate to the problem.

Thanks for anyone who tried to solve this.
I have a workaround for this issue. As nothing worked for me and running in verbose did not give enough information, I decided to re-install the Pi OS. And it fixed the issue.
